# Is there a way to get the size of a text-sprite in Ext JS4?

Tags: extjs, draw

I'm drawing some labels on sprites and have to rotate them.

But they're positioned with their top-left-corner and rotated at their center, so I have to know *where* the center is. But there is no `.width` or `getWidth()` that works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sprite.getBBox()` that will return an object with x, y, width, and height properties: [Ext.draw.Sprite#getBBox](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.draw.Sprite-method-getBBox)

Answer (score 0):

sprite.getBBox().width will return the width of sprite